# Unexpected transaction flow in WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, transactions

I have a typical WCF 4.0 service that uses `wsHttpBinding` with `transactionFlow="true"`  setting:

```
[OperationContract]
[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
[FaultContract(typeof(Invalid))]
void DoWork();
```

and here is my server-side implementation:

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
    TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable,
    TransactionTimeout = "00:00:15",
    ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = false
)]
public class MyService: IMyService {

    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = false)]
    public void DoWork() {
        if (System.Transactions.Transaction.Current == null)
            Trace.TraceInformation("WTF?!");
    }
}
```

and the client side call:

```
channel.DoWork(); // `Transaction.Current` is null at server-side as expected

using (var tx = new TransactionScope()) {
    channel.DoWork(); // Transaction.Current is still null at server-side! :(
    // .......  
}
```

when I change `TransactionScopeRequired` to `true` I get my expected distributed transaction at server-side but now I get it even when calling without an outer scope:

```
channel.DoWork(); // Transaction.Current is not null
```

and what's most annoying it rolls back any of my inner *completed* scopes if I return `Invalid` fault! That means I'm forced to always use explicit transaction scopes when calling my service despite `TransactionFlowOption.Allowed`. Why is that?

I tried to add `TransactionAutoComplete = false` to `OperationBehavior` declaration in hope of fixing the issue but got

> System.InvalidOperationException: TThe operation 'Create' on contract
> 'IUserIdentityStore' is configured with TransactionAutoComplete set to
> false and with ConcurrencyMode not set to Single.
> TransactionAutoComplete set to false requires ConcurrencyMode.Single.

which is just ridiculous.

In other words - how can I get optional transaction flow behavior and no auto-rollback when I return the declared fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TransactionScopeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute.transactionscoperequired%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation clearly states that if TransactionScopeRequired is false, the method will allways execute without a transaction.

As for the automatic rollback problem, if TransactionAutoComplete is set to true, all unhandled exceptions (Faults are Exceptions) will indeed rollback the transaction, which makes sense: there was a problem with this participant of a distributed transaction, thus the transaction must be rolled back.  If you say the Invalid fault is not really a fault, then you should use another mechanism to indicate success or failure, like returning a result code from your service.

Next, your service definition seems a bit odd to me: 
InstanceContextMode is set to Single, which indicates your service will be a singleton: there will be only 1 instance of your service running.  Furthermore, ConcurrencyMode is set to Multiple, which indicates that multiple clients can use that single instance at the same time.

I advise you to set InstanceContextMode to PerCall and ConcurrencyMode to Single, which will create a new dedicated service instance for every client call.  There is an excellent article on WCF concurrency on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and).